# Update order status with administrator comment

Tags: 7, commerce, comments

I need a way to be able to allow an admin user post an order comment when they update the order status that the owner of the order would then get posted on their order. This would both be viewable from the owner of the order, when the owner of the order was logged in under their order history view of that particular order, but would at the same time, get an email with these update comments. Ubercart 2 did this quite well. I imagine Drupal Commerce is capable, but how?

Answer (score 0):

In Commerce this is not provided as a part of core.
It is provided by the [Commerce Message](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_message) module.
In addition to that, the [Commerce Backoffice](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_backoffice) module provides an improved view that allows you to view a summary of an order (and send a message) directly from the order view.

Both are included in [Commerce Kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), in case you want a quick demo.

Comment: Thank you much, Bojan!

In fact, I am using Commerce Kickstart right now, but I do not see simple settings to make this happen. As I overlooking something?

Tom

Comment: What is also strange is that an an "admin" user, I can create an order for myself, go to "Order History" > "View order", and the "Order History" info is displayed at the bottom. This is NOT the case for an authenticated user. Where is the permission set for this?

Tom

Comment: I suppose if it was listed in bright red and blinking text, I would have found it quicker. The answer to my own question is this:

!. go to permissions
2. go to the "filter" section
3. under "Use the Commerce Order Message text format", choose "authenticated user"
4. save

Done.

Tom

Comment: A few more details I forgot to add. You also have to go into views and edit the "Commerce Message: Order messages" (this is of coarse if you have wisely pre-installed Kickstart Commerce as I have), under "Entity content settings", change "access" from "Administer orders" to "View own Order orders". Apply and save.